# asp.net seo url routing redirect the different page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, seo, url-routing

I prepare URL SEO that my page like www.abc.com/product. I am showing my product details Inside the this link productDetails.aspx with the url routing. It is working fine it shows to me product details but If I try to enter contact page or home page on the  www.acbc.com/contact or www.acbc.com/home page redirect the here **routes.MapPageRoute("prdct", "{ProductNameSeo}", "~/productDetails.aspx");** 
productDetails.aspx why it is redirect the this page.

I want to enter if user click the this link abc.com/contact , should be go contact.aspx  page but it goes the productDetails.aspx

please I need help ;

Code is here:

1- I Added the route (or routes) at application start.

```
//In Global.asax
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("lnkh", "home", "~/default.aspx");
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("lnkc", "contact", "~/contact.aspx");

    routes.MapPageRoute("prdct", "{ProductNameSeo}", "~/productDetails.aspx");  
   //  generic link to show product inside the mssql

}
```

Comment: I solved that probleblem . you need to put "/" end of the page like tihs : RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("lnkh", "home/", "~/default.aspx");

Comment: hi @user3630521 i have same issue! i mean to say how to decide the destination page depending on URL eg:1. routes.MapPageRoute("carriers", "{state}/{mcat}/{dcat}", "~/carriers.aspx");
2.routes.MapPageRoute("phones", "{state}/{mcat}/{dcat}", "~/phones.aspx");
if value in URL second parameter i.e mcat=cellphone then it must redirect to carriers.aspx. and if mcat=iphone then it must redirect to phones.aspx page how to do? any idea? I do not need slash(/) at the end of every URL!